# Parse - Query against a nested pointer?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to run a query against a nested pointer in an object.
According to the docs dot notation is supported when the nested pointer is included in the query, but this doesn't seem to work. It's not returning `state == %@ AND event.expirationDate > %@`

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "to == %@ AND (state == %@ OR (state == %@ AND event.expirationDate > %@))",
        User.currentUser(),
        EventInvitation.State.Accepted.rawValue,
        EventInvitation.State.Pending.rawValue,
        NSDate())

let query = EventInvitation.queryWithPredicate(predicate)
query.includeKey("event")
query.includeKey("from")
```

Comment: I wonder whether its the dot notation in the predicate.  Can you experiment with greaterThan() on event.expirationDate?  If that works, you can refactor this query into three and run them with Query.or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this

```
let acceptedQuery = EventInvitation.query()
    .whereKey("state", equalTo: EventInvitation.State.Accepted.rawValue)
    .whereKey("to", equalTo: User.currentUser())

let pendingQuery = EventInvitation.query()
    .whereKey("state", equalTo: EventInvitation.State.Pending.rawValue)
    .whereKey("event", matchesQuery: Event.query().whereKey("expirationDate", greaterThan: NSDate()))
    .whereKey("to", equalTo: User.currentUser())

let finalQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([acceptedQuery, pendingQuery])
    .includeKey("from")
    .includeKey("event")
```